# Spring Boot ignores CSS / JS when loading page

Tags: java, css, spring-boot, mustache

My page (order.mustache) uses several CSS styles (external and local), images, background video and JS element. Most of the page layout is described in style.css, which is located in the 'resourses/static/css' directory.

When I start a page through Chrome as an HTML document, it displays correctly. But if I run it through Spring Boot (as a mustache page) - all local styles, images, JS and even youtube videos are ignored.

The browser console indicates an error 'Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text / html:' http: // localhost: 8080 / static / css / style.css'.' On the Response tab of the Chrome developer panel, style.css is displayed as a copy of the order.mustache page. On the Headers tab, its type is text / html.

I can’t understand at what point these changes are happening, and what should I change so that the page works properly.

[image]
[image]

HTML:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>...</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link href="../static/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type="text/css">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {
@Autowired
private ClientRepo repo;

@GetMapping
public String main(Map<String, Object> model) {
    Iterable<Client> clients = repo.findAll();
    model.put("clients", clients);
    return "order";
}

@PostMapping
public String add(@RequestParam String firstName, @RequestParam String lastName, @RequestParam String nationality,
                  @RequestParam String sex, @RequestParam Date birthDate, @RequestParam long passNumber, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Client client = new Client(firstName, lastName, nationality, sex, birthDate, passNumber);
    repo.save(client);

    Iterable<Client> clients = repo.findAll();
    model.put("clients", client);

    return "order";
}

}
```

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    MustacheViewResolver mustacheViewResolver
            = new MustacheViewResolver();
    mustacheViewResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    mustacheViewResolver.setSuffix(".mustache");
    mustacheViewResolver.setCache(false);

    return mustacheViewResolver;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to swap

```
<link href="../static/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Maybe your custom styles cannot load after bootstrap.

Do like that :

```html
<!-- My styles firstly -->
<link href="../static/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- And then bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type="text/css">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Do you have in app.properties spring.mustache.expose-request-attributes=true ?

Comment: Added, the result is the same. Honestly, I’m almost sure that it’s either the controller and the get \ post annotations, or the ViewResolver.

Comment: then add your full Controller code please:)
at least you can move your dataformat to your entity class, its more correctly(under private birthDate statement)

Comment: Added all the controller code.
Perhaps I should specify arguments for GetMapping and PostMapping, instead of using them by default? Or replace them with @RequestMapping (method = RequestMethod.GET \ POST)?

Comment: Add globally RequestMapping("/") or to both mappings ("/").  And to second mapping return "redirect:/"

Comment: I changed the mapping to '/' in both requests, in the last I set redirect. The css misinterpretation message disappeared, but now all .js, .css and .jpeg files are marked as 404.

Perhaps I will rewrite the project on Thymeleaf.
https://i.imgur.com/f4urwL2.jpg

Comment: it's work!
Changing the mapping like as your last comment + a short path to the .css file href="/css/style.css" made the styles work.

Not entirely correct, true, but I'll fix it. Thanks!  Please write this as an answer.